# Meteor: How should I write this Iron Router route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to rewrite my Iron Router adminhome router but when I click on the link to /admin/home I get the error below.

How should I rewrite this route?

```
Router.route('adminhome', {
      layoutTemplate: 'adminlayout',
      path:'/admin/home',
      template: 'adminarea',
      onBeforeAction: function() {
          if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
              this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
          } else if(!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])) {
              console.log('redirecting');
              this.redirect('/');
          } else {
              this.next();
          }
      }
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 Error: Expected template rendered with Blaze.render
    at Object.Blaze.remove (view.js:679)
    at DynamicTemplate.destroy (iron_dynamic-template.js:327)
    at null._render (iron_layout.js:400)
    at doRender (view.js:351)
    at view.js:199
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:457)
    at view.js:197
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at viewAutorun (view.js:196)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:323)
```

Here's my updated code.  The problem might be related to the `{{>yield}}` line.  That's just a guess though.

```
    Router.route('adminhome', {
      layoutTemplate: 'adminlayout',
      path:'/admin/home',
      template: 'adminarea',

      onBeforeAction: function() {
          if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
              //this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
              this.render("loadingPage");
          } else if(!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])) {
              console.log('redirecting');
              this.redirect('/');
          } else {
              this.next();
          }
      }
});


<template name="adminTemplate">
    {{#if isInRole "admin"}}
        {{> adminarea}}
    {{else}}
        Must be admin to see this...
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="adminarea">
   {{>yield}}
</template>
```

Comment: In the line of your code... this.render(this.loadingTemplate); ... replace this.loadingTemplate with the actual loading template name. Eg. this.render("LoadingTemplateName");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line of your code...

`this.render(this.loadingTemplate);`

...replace `this.loadingTemplate` with the actual loading template name.

Eg.

```
this.render("LoadingTemplateName");
```

Comment: that seemed to work but now I get: Uncaught Error: Expected template rendered with Blaze.render

Comment: Can you provide the html and javascript file please so I can reproduce what you are doing? Thanks

Comment: I've added a bit more.  I'm trying to get an old project working so I've forgotten a alot unfortunately :(

Comment: Inside the project, do "meteor update" and "meteor add ejson", as far as I can see, this should work.